Swift 5.10 lets you conform to protocols with different parameters
This Swift 5.10 code compiles in Xcode 15.4:
protocol MyProtocol {
    func foo(with parameter: Bool) -> Bool
}

class Conforms: MyProtocol {
    func foo(with anotherParameter: Bool) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}

As you can see, it assumes Conforms conforms to the protocol, even though it has a different function's parameter.
Is this expected behavior?

Yes and I believe it has been this way for a while and not just in 5.10.  And there are other changes you can do to the method signature without breaking protocol conformance, like ignoring the parameter or give it a default value. (Strange) example: func foo(with _: Bool = false) -> Bool

Other than that I find the question a bit strange, the code compiles but you ask if this is expected behaviour?

Yeah, I was not sure if it was a bug. But I guess it's not if you say it's been around for a while

@JoakimDanielson I believe it has always been this way, since day one of Swift 1. Internal parameter names have never been in any context part of a method's signature. And rightly so.

That is expected behaviour. The names parameter and anotherParameter are merely placeholders that tell you how to refer to the parameter in the code internal to the function. In other words, they are just an implementation detail.
The word with in both function definitions, however, is a label to be used by callers. You'll find, if those do not agree, there is error.
protocol MyProtocol {
    func foo(with parameter: Bool) -> Bool
}

class Conforms: MyProtocol {
 func foo(without anotherParameter: Bool) -> Bool // Error here
 {
     true
 }
}

gives the following error on the marked line
Instance method 'foo(without:)' has different argument labels from those required by protocol 'MyProtocol' ('foo(with:)')

and advises you to chang the label to with.
